# How to fix No URL error in implementing kafka connect

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I need to implement Kafka connect, so I have referred the video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r7LUbtOFcQI
and implemented steps accordingly.
While starting the Kafka connect, I need to run the CURL command. while running the below command i am facing an issue as

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{
"name": "jdbc_source_connector",
"config": {
"connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector",
"tasks.max":2,
"connection.url": "jdbc:mysql://69.61.32.102:3306/ssptest",
"connection.user": "sspuser",
"connection.password": "xxx",
"topic.prefix": "",
"poll.interval.ms" : 3600000,
"table.whitelist" : "Persons",
"mode":"incrementing"
}
}'http://localhost:8083/connectors
```

I am facing an error as,
curl: no URL specified
Can anyone please suggest a solution to fix the error

[image: my screenshot in ubuntu terminal]

Comment: You are missing a space after the curl data

Comment: Also, you have Postman, so you should ideally use that